# Insert Radiobuttons in JTable Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jtable, netbeans-6.9, jradiobutton

I am populating Employee Data in JTable using Netbeans. I want to add Radiobutton in each row, so that user can select any row and can perform actions like Update/Delete,etc.
Here is my code for TableModel:

```
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

    model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[] {"Select","Employee ID","Name","Surname","Birth Place","Genre","Home","Marital Status","Phone","Age","Department"});
    try{
    con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+database,"root","123456");
    Statement s = con.createStatement ();
    s.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM Employee");
    ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet ();
    rs.next ();
    String eid = rs.getString ("emp_no");
    String name = rs.getString ("name");
    String surname = rs.getString ("surname");
    String pbirth = rs.getString ("place_birth");
    String genre = rs.getString ("genre");
    String home = rs.getString ("home");
    String mstatus = rs.getString ("marital_status");
    String ph = rs.getString ("phone");
    int age = rs.getInt ("age");
    String dept = rs.getString ("department");
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
    model.addRow(new Object[] {?,eid, name, surname, pbirth, genre, home, mstatus, ph, age, dept});
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
    this.jTable1.setModel(model);
```

In first column of every row i want to insert a radiobutton. Please suggest me.
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement **[TableCellEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html)** and override **getTableCellEditorComponent** like this

```
public java.awt.Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)

{
            return new JRadioButton();
}
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT:**
You can write like this

```
this.jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor(){
    @Override
    public java.awt.Component getTableCellEditorComponent(javax.swing.JTable table, java.lang.Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        return new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    }

    @Override
    public java.lang.Object getCellEditorValue() {
return null;//Here you can return the radio button status
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(java.util.EventObject anEvent) {
        return false; //uneditable cell
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSelectCell(java.util.EventObject anEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelCellEditing() {       
    }

    @Override
    public void addCellEditorListener(javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener l) {
    }

    @Override
    public void removeCellEditorListener(javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener l) {
    }

});
```

You can take out the cell editor implementation to a separate class.

Also you have to set the flags accordingly to your requirement.

Comment: Hi can you tell in my code context that how should I call this method?

Comment: @RaviG I never saw good and correct Renderer/Editor for JRadioButton, notice maybe my bad that I want to implements JRadioButton in the ButtonGroup

Comment: @mKorbel You may add these radio buttons explicitely to the ButtonGroup?

Comment: When I added this code, netbeans put red lines in this code showing errors(illegal start of type and blah blah) !!! Please help...

Comment: If you can show me your complete code (in a URL), I can plug this.

Comment: @RaviG Kindly refer to this link:
[CodeFile](http://www.mediafire.com/?v7m4u1e4q41m42r)

Comment: @RaviG I added this code into my project file. When i run, it shows empty cells in first column (in which radiobuttons should appear!!!)
Can you please fix this? I appreciate your help...

Comment: That is because of model.addRow(new Object[] { null, eid, name, surname, pbirth, genre, home, mstatus, ph, age, dept });

Comment: Try changing it to model.addRow(new Object[] { eid, eid, name, surname, pbirth, genre, home, mstatus, ph, age, dept });

Comment: @RaviG Not working with eid either!!!
It shows eid number in first column when i do as:
model.addRow(new Object[] { eid, eid, name, surname, pbirth, genre, home, mstatus, ph, age, dept });

Comment: @NidaSulheri Looking into it which may take some time. Will post once I find a solution.

Comment: @NidaSulheri Finally could do that and is availabe [Here](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?f68r1aio0f12ho1). I took help and reference from [Java2S](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/RadioButtonTableExample.htm)

Comment: @RaviG wow!!! it is working now. Now radiobuttons are displaying in first column. You have been great help to me. thanks for your time.
I will resume working on this project tomorrow. If i find any difficulty in radiobuttons matter, i hope you will help me out.

Comment: @NidaSulheri Great to see that it is working. In case of difficulty, you can post comment here only.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest

1. change [JRadioButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton) to [JCheckBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox), because [JCheckBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox) in the [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) respresents only `Boolean` value
2. don't use generated code from NetBeans, write code by your hands

Comment: Ok, I will have no problem in using checkboxes, but atleast give me some code to add checkboxes to jtable first column !!!
I have customized tablemodel(as you can see in above code), that means that I am writing table code by my hands...

Comment: @Nida Sulheri please I linked tutorial there not for joking from your person, follows examples from tutorial, 3quaters of them contains JCheckBox in the JTable