# Overriding JTable's DefaultTableCellRenderer to center all the cells in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I've got a problem I can't get rid of.

Just so you know, I'm fairly new to using JTables, so the answer might be simple, but I can't find a solution :/

So, I've got a JTable using an AbstractTableModel, which overrides the

```
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex_p)
```

method, to tell the type of each column to be displayed. One of them is a Boolean.

When I create a simple JTable, using

```
    table_l = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
```

everything is fine, and Boolean values are correctly displayed using checkboxes (on/off).

Now, I'd like to center the text on each cell (and, possibly more options later).

So I define a new DefaultTableCellRenderer for each column, like this :

```
    DefaultTableCellRenderer cellRenderer_l = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
          // delegate the rendering part to the default renderer (am i right ???)
          Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
          return comp;
        }
    }
```

and then I just set the horizontal alignment of this CellRender with :

```
    cellRenderer_l.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
```

Then I install this new CellRenderer on each column of the JTable :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < table_l.getColumnCount(); ++i) {
        table_l.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(cellRenderer_l);
    }
```

But, with the new CellRenderer, the displayed JTable isn't using the getColumnClass() method of my TableModel anymore, and thus just display "true/false" String on Boolean values.

I don't know how to get it to still use the getColumnClass() as before.

If someone has the answer...
Thank you

EDIT:
thanks for all the clarifications you made.
In fact, my real question was : "how to affect all DefaultRenderer of a JTable to make them center their result in the JTable's cells"

Comment: Check this. You may get a clue. Here I suggested to add radio buttons in the table column. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117716/insert-radiobuttons-in-jtable-netbeans/9117895#9117895

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, isn't there any simpler solution ?  All I want to do, in fact, is defining a new DefaultCellRenderer which does exactly like the default used by the JTable, but just center text in cells

Comment: if per-column renderers are set, those are used irrespective of the per-class defaults (see the JTable source for the exact lookup logic)

Comment: @kleopatra thanks for your reply, I wasn't aware of that. I then tried to redefine DefaultCellRenderer for Object, Number and Boolean, and call setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER) of those new DefaultCellRenderer, but with no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For applying the same visual decoration to all rendering components (if that's what you *really* want, be careful, it might have an usability penalty!) you can override the JTable's preparedRenderer method:

```
@Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
    Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(...);
    if (comp instanceof JLabel) {
        ((JLabel) comp).setHorizontalAlignment(...);
    }
    return comp;
}
```

BTW: this approach is violating the rule to *not* subclass JSomething for application needs. You might consider using [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net) which formally supports visually decorating rendering components. So instead of subclassing, you would register a Highlighter with the table:

```
JXTable table = ...
table.addHighlighter(new AlignmentHighlighter(CENTER), HighlightPredicate.ALWAYS);
```

Comment: thanks for the JXTable example. I updated my project, so now I use only JXTables. It got a nice high(er)-level API, and suits perfectly my needs. Thanks again !

Answer (score 5):

The default cell [renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) already does this for values of type `Boolean.class`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513). If this is not sufficient, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits any problems you encounter.

Addendum: If you need to further customize a `DefaultTableCellRenderer`, specify the renderer for the applicable type using `setDefaultRenderer()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513).

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, yourCellRenderer);
```

[image]

Comment: yep, I know the default renderer handles Boolean as checkboxes. All I want to do, in fact, is defining a new DefaultCellRenderer which does exactly like the default used by the JTable, but just center text in cells

Comment: I think you want to apply the renderer by class, rather than by column; more above.

Comment: thanks for the clue. I could define many renderers, one for each possible type in my JTables, and then customize them. But I would like to "tell" the JTable : "just use your default renderer, but center the result in the cell". Isn't there a simple way to do that ? :(

Comment: I think `CENTER` is the default for both `DefaultTableCellRenderer` and `DefaultCellEditor(JCheckBox)`. Are you seeing somethting different?

Comment: CENTER is the default for JCheckBox, but String are left-aligned, while Numbers are right-aligned. I want my JTable to center the content of every cell, without regarding its type

Comment: But, seeing your replies and documentation, I'm starting thinking that I will have to replace the renderer for all the possible Types in my JTable I want to be centered. Like installing new Renderers for String, new Renderers for Number etc...

Comment: nitpicking: the default renderer for booleans is _not_ of type DefaultTableCellRenderer and Center is _not_ the default alignment for DefaultTableCellRenderer:-) +1 for what you really mean

Comment: @adrien.pain I doubt that you (read: your users) _really_ want numbers to be centered :-) Anyway, you probably want to edit your question and add the clarification there

Comment: @kleopatra highlights a crucial distinction: `JTable` default renderers also implement `UIResource` and invoke `setHorizontalAlignment()` as [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). If you _really_ want to change the default alignment, you can usually replace the default renderer with one derived from `DefaultTableCellRenderer`.

Comment: @trashgod yep, I want to choose the default alignment, replacing the default renderer. But how to simply do it please ?

Comment: @kleopatra's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14771059/230513) is dispositive; don't hesitate to accept that answer, but please update your question to reflect the intent to affect _all_ renderers.

Comment: @kleopatra thanks for your reply. I'll accept your answer as the correct answer I was looking for