# Java Swing's equivalent for WPF's Data Templates

Tags: java, swing, datatemplate

In a Swing application, I'm drawing elements on a `JPanel` overriding the `paintComponent` method.

I have to draw cats, dogs, camels, and more... I guess that polluting `paintComponent` with a series of `if (... instanceof ...)` statements would be a bad thing, so I'm looking for another way to draw my pets.

With WPF ( C# ), I'd have used [Data Templates](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/), i.e. a way to tell the View how to display a Model entity.

So, I came up with a solution ported from JS:

```
import my.super.Callback; // Because Runnable does not take parameters.

/**
 * The class that draws in the canvas.
 */
public class CanvasDrawer {
    private HashMap<Class, Callback<Graphics2D, Object>> drawers;
    private Graphics2D graphics;

    public CanvasDrawer(Graphics2D g) {
        graphics = g;
        drawers = new HashMap<Class, Callback<Graphics2D, Object>>();
    }

    /**
     * Defines a way to draw the objects of a certain type in the canvas.
     */
    public <T> void setDataTemplate(Class<T> type, Callback<Graphics2D, T> drawer) {
        drawers.put(type, (Callback<Graphics2D, Object>)drawer);
    }

    /**
     * Actually draws an object in the canvas.
     */
    public void draw(Object object) {
        drawers.get(object.getClass()).run(graphics, object);
    }
}
```

... Which could be used like this:

```
class HuntingPartyView extends JPanel {
    CanvasDrawer drawer;

    public HuntingPartyView() {
        drawer = new CanvasDrawer((Graphics2D)getGraphics());

        // Where the drawImage method is intentionally skipped in this code.
        drawer.setDataTemplate(   Cat.class, (g, o) -> drawImage(g, 'res/cat.png',    o.x, o.y));
        drawer.setDataTemplate(   Dog.class, (g, o) -> drawImage(g, 'res/dog.png',    o.x, o.y));
        drawer.setDataTemplate(Sniper.class, (g, o) -> drawImage(g, 'res/sniper.png', o.x, o.y));
        drawer.setDataTemplate(Ranger.class, (g, o) -> drawImage(g, 'res/ranger.png', o.x, o.y));
    }

    @Override
    public void repaintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // Where Game is part of the Model layer.
        for (Animal animal : Game.singleton.animalList) drawer.draw(animal);
        for (Hunter hunter : Game.singleton.hunterList) drawer.draw(hunter);
    }
}
```

... But the code of the `CanvasDrawer` above gives me an unchecked warning when I compile it:

```
$ javac *.java -d out -Xdiags:verbose -Xlint:unchecked
CanvasDrawer.java:15: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
                drawers.put(type, (Callback<Graphics2D, Object>)drawer);
                                                                ^
  required: Callback<Graphics2D,Object>
  found:    Callback<Graphics2D,T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>setDataTemplate(Class<T>,Callback<Graphics2D,T>)
1 warning
```

**Question 1.** Did I miss something during my research? I mean: do *Data Templates* exist in Java Swing?
**Question 2.** Is there another way to do what I want to do? Am I going the right way?
**Question 3.** Do I really have to use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`?

Comment: See [*A Swing Architecture Overview*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html).

Comment: I don't get it: I retain that the Controller has been collapsed in the View. To me, it sounds like the `...Listener` classes are the Controllers, and they are _collapsed_ because one controller could be an anonymous class. I also didn't know that thing with the components models; are you suggesting that I use those data models somehow?

Answer (score 1):

> I guess that polluting paintComponent with a series of if (... instanceof ...) statements would be a bad thing

Correct.

One way is to to just keep an ArrayList of `Animals` where each animal has a draw method to paint itself.

Something like:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for (Animal animal: animals)
    {
        animal.draw(g);
    }
}
```

`Animal` can be a simple interface or an abstract class.

Comment: Isn't it a bad thing to put such a _view-ui-painting logic_ in the --- supposedly decoupled --- model ?

Answer (score 1):

With reference to [*A Swing Architecture Overview*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html), a complete guide to Swing design is beyond the scope of this site, but a few guidelines may help you going forward.

1. **Did I miss something during my research?** I mean: do [Data Templates](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/) exist in Java Swing? Not explicitly. Focusing on the tutorial example, a Swing `JList` displays a `ListModel<E>`. The direct subclass, `AbstractListModel<E>`, adds event listener management using the scheme examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2159803/230513). The concrete subclass, `DefaultListModel<E>`, is a typical implementation. Depending on need, your model might implement the interface directly, leverage the event plumbing of the abstract model or simply contain a concrete model instance, as outlined in [*How to Use Lists: Creating a Model*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#creating).
2. **Is there another way to do what I want to do? Am I going the right way?** Several common ways to implement the *observer pattern* are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).
3. **Do I really have to use @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")?** Instead of a raw class like `Object`, you can specify a type parameter such as `CanvasDrawer<T>`, as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). See also [*Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html).
4. **Isn't it a bad thing to put such a view-ui-painting logic in the—supposedly decoupled—model?** The [example outlined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44290888/230513) is a *view* component; the *model* might contain a `List<Animal>` that is accessed when the observing *view* updates itself in response to an event.
5. **It sounds like the `…Listener` classes are the controller; and they are collapsed because one controller could be an anonymous class.** One appealing design approach allows clients to *inject* a new controller, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14016425/230513) for [jmapviewer](/questions/tagged/jmapviewer).
6. **Are you suggesting that I use those data models somehow?** Only where appropriate. There are simply too many ways to display a `List<Animal>` to say more.

Comment: I don't understand; your update uses the type-token pattern I cited.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was incomplete. **3**: It's the purpose of `Callback<Graphics2D, T>`. Did you mean something else? --- **4**: I couldn't get a thing. My point is: is that MVC compliant to declare a `draw` view dependent method in middle of the model layer? --- **5**: So they... Can be? Or can't? In the example you gave, the controller is injected with the view so the controller can call `addObserver(this)` ( well, something like this ) by itself. --- **PS**: What is _type-token pattern_?

Comment: I'm not sure about the rest, but _type-token_ would include your usage above and `JTable::setDefaultRenderer`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14770029/230513); calling a _pattern_ may be unwarranted.